# MVC Partial View with List Model

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, renderpartial

I have a news item page and I would like to include a partial view presenting a list of the latest 5 news items. However, I get a

> this dictionary requires a model item of type
>   'System.Collections.Generic.List

error message. I'm assuming the main view is strong typed to present a single item, whereas the partial view is strongly typed with a generic list and the two don't match.

Controller

```
public ActionResult NewsItem(int newsId, string newsTitle)
{
    var q = _ctx.tblNews.Single(x => x.newsID == newsId);

    return View(q);
}

public ActionResult NewsLatest()
{
    var q = _ctx.tblNews.OrderBy(x => x.newsCreateDate)
            .Where(x => x.WebsiteID == 2 && x.newsPublish).Take(5).ToList();
    return View(q);
}
```

View (simplified)

```
@using MyMVC.Models
@model tblNews

<h2>@Model.newsTitle</h2>
@Html.Raw(Model.newsText)
<p>@Model.newsCreateDate</p>
@Html.RenderPartial("NewsLatest")
```

Partial View

```
@using MyMVC.Helpers
@model List<MyMVC.Models.tblNews>

<table>
    @foreach (var x in Model)
    {
        <tr>
            <td>
                @Html.ActionLink(x.newsTitle, "NewsItem", new { newsId = x.newsID, newsTitle = x.newsTitle.ToSeoUrl() })<br />
                <hr />
            </td>
        </tr>
    }
</table>
```

I tried this in the view:

```
@{
    Html.RenderPartial("NewsLatest", new List<tblNews> { new tblNews()});
}
```

but it looks like the ActionResult doesn't get fired trying i this way.

There are a few questions on SO relating to this. But I just can't get my head around the solutions. The penny isn't dropping!

Do I really have to create a view model that incorporates the news item data and the list of news items?

Comment: Error is quite self explanatory, model you are passing is of different type that what view is expecting.

Comment: _"Do I really have to create a view model"_? Why would you not want to do it the correct way. But an alternative is to use `@Html.Action("NewsLatest")` where you call the controller method that returns the partial view (or `@{ Html.RenderAction("NewsLatest"); }`)

Comment: public ActionResult NewsLatest() there is no place for list of items